# difference between %{count} and %<count>s in validation message

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am used to the approach below when displaying a validation message

```
class Person < ApplicationRecord
  validates :bio, length: { maximum: 1000,
    too_long: "%{count} characters is the maximum allowed" }
end
```

However, I just found out that below is also possible. But I could not find any documentation on `%<>s` format. And what is the use of `s` found at the end?

```
    too_long: "%<count>s characters is the maximum allowed" }
```

Can someone explain the difference between these syntaxes? Or provide a documentation link on `%<>s`

reference:
https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html#length

Comment: @TomLord At first, I actually thought it was a typo. I tried changing  ```%<count>s``` to ```%<count>``` but it just cause an ```invalid format``` error. But with ```%<count>s characters```, the actual output is ```1000 characters```, not ```1000s characters```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That `s` in `%<...>s` denotes "string". From the [`sprintf`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-3.1.0/Kernel.html#sprintf-method) docs:

> For more complex formatting, Ruby supports a reference by name. `%<name>s` style uses format style, but `%{name}` style doesn't.

Example:

```
sprintf('%<count>s characters', count: '2,300')
=> "2,300 characters"
```

Answer (score 3):

Rails uses `I18n` internally to interpolate error messages. So for answers we should refer to its documentation. Or [its source](https://github.com/ruby-i18n/i18n/blob/0888807ab2fe4f4c8a4b780f5654a8175df61feb/lib/i18n/interpolate/ruby.rb#L5) - the latter explains (hopefully) why `%<>s` pattern works for you.

But honestly I would avoid using non-documented features. If Rails' team decides to change the error messages interpolation machinery one day your code becomes broken - just because you relied on the internals and their non-documented features. This is unlikely to happen in this particular case, but still...

Comment: I wasn't aware that they reinvented the wheel and always assumed it's plain `sprintf` under the hood.

Comment: As far as I see for `%<>` patterns it is `sprintf` all in all, just with some additional boilerplate around.

Comment: You're right, I missed the `sprintf` call at the very bottom.